# Scrape the value of "Elevation" from the Website page using JAVA

Tags: java

I am making a program to **scrape** the value of Elevation from a web page. The webpage address is - https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=35.227085&y=-80.843123&units=Meters&output=json

When we open the above link, the webpage displayed is -

{"USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service":{"Elevation_Query"{"x":35.227085,"y":-80.843123,"Data_Source":"3DEP 1/3 arc-second","Elevation":"-1000000","Units":"Meters"}}}

I am not able to print the value of only Elevation i.e, -1000000 from the data displayed on the webpage. I am required to do it using JAVA. Please help. I am new to programming.

I tried a code below. But is prints  entire content of webpage. I require only elevation value.

```
URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader br;
  

    try {
        url = new URL("https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=35.227085&y=-80.843124&units=Meters&output=json");
        is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

     //  System.out.println (br.lines());
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);    
        }
```

I want only the elevation value using JAVA.

Comment: you are new in Java, yet you attempt to perform web scraping using Java?

Comment: It is related to my project work. I have to find elevation values for a large number of latitudes and longitudes and do some kind of calculations on these elevation values.

Comment: I did a lot of searching on JSON. I couldnot solve this problem. I tried to convert the string line into character array and then print the particular value of elevation, but it gave me null exception error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert InputStream into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794427/convert-inputstream-into-json)

Answer (score 1):

This URL contains `json` data, so you need to use any json framework, e.g. **Jackson**.

First of all, you have to define json model of the returned message:

```
public static class Model {
    @JsonProperty("USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service")
    private ElevationPointQuery elevationPointQuery;

    public static class ElevationPointQuery {
        @JsonProperty("Elevation_Query")
        private Data data;

        public static class Data {
            @JsonProperty
            private double x;
            @JsonProperty
            private double y;
            @JsonProperty("Data_Source")
            private String dataSource;
            @JsonProperty("Elevation")
            private String elevation;
            @JsonProperty("Units")
            private String units;
        }

    }
}
```

Then you have to define method, that reads json message from given url and returns the model:

```
private static <T> T readJsonByUrl(URL url, Class<T> cls) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {
        return new ObjectMapper().readerFor(cls).readValue(in);
    }
}
```

Finally, you are ready to read the model and get required data:

```
final URL url = new URL("https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=35.227085&y=-80.843124&units=Meters&output=json");
Model data = readJsonByUrl(url, Model.class);
System.out.println("Elevation = " + data.elevationPointQuery.data.elevation);
```

---

To use **Jackson**, you have to add following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.8'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
```

Comment: When i am putting the code in eclipse, it is showing error at ObjectMapper().What should i do?

Comment: You have to add `Jackson` dependencies

Comment: I am asking a lot sir, but can you give a link for jackson dependency.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Jackson JSON Tutorial by Baeldung - https://www.baeldung.com/jackson

Comment: Is there any kind of jar file,which i can add in eclipse and run the code.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.8