# How do I convert an InputStream into a Map in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, hashmap, inputstream

Suppose I have an **InputStream** that contains JSON data, and I want to convert it to a Map(Key Value Pairs), so for example I can write that to a log file.

What is the easiest way to take the InputStream and convert it to a Map?

```
public String convertInputStreamToMap(InputStream isobj) {
    // ???
}
```

I've tried converting to **String** which works as expected but when the data is really long the data will be incomplete. So I want some easiest way to directly convert this to Map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert InputStream into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794427/convert-inputstream-into-json)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read / convert an InputStream into a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Isn't JSON way more suited to write to a log file than a Map.toString()?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObjectMapper` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` to directly convert inputstream to Map:
for example:

```
objectMapper.readValue(is, Map.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a built-in class in groovy to parse json: [groovy.json.JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)

it has `parse` method that accepts almost any source including InputStream

```
def url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'.toURL()

def json = url.withInputStream{inputStream->
    new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(inputStream)
}

println json.headers
```

and if you want to convert InputStream to String, groovy provides additional methods to work with InputStream class: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html

the following code reads the content of this InputStream using specified charset and returns it as a String.

```
String s = inputStream.getText("UTF-8")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.